# Django Internationalization gives fuzzy with capital letters

Tags: django, internationalization, django-1.7, po

I am setting up internationalization for a Django project (1.7).

I am successfully generating `.po` files, however, I have entries such as:

```
#: my_app/templates/my_app/profile.html:155
#, fuzzy
#| msgid "Court"
msgid "court"
msgstr ""
```

From what I understand `, fuzzy` will cause the translation not to happen. I would like the capitalization to remain as is, so how can I make the translations match the original words?

I imagine maybe those can be forced to be generated as two separate entries in `.po` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before execution of `makemessages` you had a `msgid "Court"` in the `.po` file.  Django decided that the "court" is very similar to "Court" and created a "fuzzy" record with the same translation (which was empty).

Just delete the `#, fuzzy` and `#| msgid "Court"` lines and run the `compilemessages`:

```
#: some file.html
msgid "Court"
msgstr "Tribunal"

#: my_app/templates/my_app/profile.html:155
msgid "court"
msgstr "tribunal"
```